# List of local folder access restrictions for UWP desktop app?

Tags: deployment, uwp, restriction

Is there a list of restricted folders access for UWP desktop apps under Windows 10?  My app will need access to the following:

ProgramData

ProgramFiles  (not x86 since all will be 64bit)

User[accountname]\AppData\Local

User[accountname]\AppData\Roaming

Also, could someone point me to how to deploy my application without going thru the MS Store?  I've done "developer side grade" deployments to my other PCs but this is NOT going to fly for my end users obviously ... so I was hoping there is an easier way to deploy for end users and NOT using MS store?

Cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Web Install feature. About the restricted access to the folders UWP Applications cannot get access to that kind of folders

Web Install

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/installing-windows10-apps-web

Folders

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Comment: Thanks for the web link, but that suggests the end user will need to have their "device/computer" in "sideload or developer" mode.  ... see quote "For users to install your app, you will need to sign the app package with a trusted certificate. You can use a third party paid certificate from a trusted certification authority to sign your app package. If a third party certificate is used, the user will need to have their device in either sideload or developer mode to install and run your app."

Comment: Thanks for the folders link ... looks like UWP is unable to access another applications  folder (show stopper for me to use UWP).  For example, I need read/write access to User\[accountname]\AppData\Local\SomeOtherAppThatIsNotMine ... it seems UWP would only allow me access to User\[accountname]\AppData\Local\MyApp.

Comment: Requiring the end user to have their PC in "sideload" or "developer" mode is a show stopper also ... seems the ONLY way around this is to deploy to MS store and install from there which is not something my end users will be happy about at all.  But thanks for the links, it's just one more nail in the UWP coffin ... seems less functional than the old "Click Once" deployments.

Comment: you are right. UWP is a sandbox not like WPF or other tech...

Comment: Windows Desktop has been defaulted to allow side-loads for several years now. A user / Enterprise could turn it off though. Your app can access other folders if the user gives permissions via `FolderPicker` or the `broadFilesystemAccess` capability.